# Does Portuguese have remnants of a case system?

Tags: gramática, pronomes, linguística, caso-gramatical

Just like in English, Portuguese nouns don't inflect according to grammatical case. However, in English, traces of a case system (nominative, genitive, dative, accusative) are found in question words like *whose* (*gen.*) or *whom* (*dat.*) or in personal pronouns like *I* (*nom.*) or *my* (*gen.*) etc.

In Portuguese, there's *eu*, *me* and *mim*. Are there question words for 
*whose* or *whom* (which don't use *de*, *para*, etc.)?

**Where can I see other remnants of a case system in Portuguese?**

Comment: There is also *cujo* / *cuja* / *cujos* / *cujas* (*whose*), which are remnants of Latin genitive.

Answer (score 3):

As @bfavaretto mentioned, we also have [*cujo*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cujo) and its derivatives but also *quem* which [translates as *whom*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/quem). Here's a Wikipedia [article about this](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Declina%C3%A7%C3%A3o_na_l%C3%ADngua_portuguesa) (Only available in Portuguese).

Comment: Downvoters, we're always interested in knowing why you consider an answer as bad or wrong.

Comment: I haven't downvoted your answer but I haven't upvoted it either.  It's more a comment with links than an answer.  In addition, you say that "quem" translates as "whom" and it seems to me you're wrong.  e.g. "Quem roubou o meu isqueiro?", "Eu não sei quem disse isso."  "Eu não tenho quem me ajude"  (  "Who stole my lighter?"., "I don't know who said that.", "I have no one to help me".  I suggest that you improve your answer.

Comment: @Centaurus Not wrong, but you're right that it's not as common. "This person, whom I like, is my friend."/"Esta pessoa, de quem eu eu gosto, é minha amiga.". So, I guess it's more _de quem_, which can translate to at least _whose_ and _whom_. Unfortunately, I don't know what else I can improve my answer with. Any suggestions?

Comment: Someone,   It's all about "defining" and "non-defining" clauses.  Don't try to generalize and say that "de quem" translates as "whom".   "De quem" may translate as "whose", "who", "whom", "whoever", etc (see the differences between the sentences "de quem eu gosto, nem às paredes confesso",  "de quem é esse livro?", "seja de quem tiver sido a ideia, ela não vai funcionar" etc .